# hosted on aws, still page not available

Tags: amazon-web-services, wordpress

I have registered a domain www.techsteroid.com with godaddy and hosted on aws ec2 instance with public dns ec2-52-8-152-90.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com . I have installed wordpress and associated elastic ip address and updated it in godaddy. Then, my website was redirecting to correct page like this

```
http://www.techsteroid.com/
```

but on clicking on any link, address bar will show public dns ie

```
http://ec2-52-8-152-90.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/2016/06/11/hello-world/
```

instead of

```
http://techsteroid.com/2016/06/11/hello-world/
```

To fix it I created a hosted zone, imported zone file, and updated nameservers in godaddy. But since then website is not even opening. It says www...com can't ebe reached. Niether of company's support are able to resolve this problem.

The ss's are [image]
[image]
The problem now is how should I be able to connect to the site by its domain on my network.  In permalinks setting, I am seeing this
[image]

Comment: I can't understand why people are downvoting. There are plenty of questions with similar problems with tens of upvotes.

Comment: You are getting downvoted because you have not dedicated ample time to truly understanding the technologies you are using, and because of this, are flailing around and causing further confusion for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

OK, first, the DNS changes you made *are* working. I can pull up the site without issue.

Your NS servers point to Route53 as expected:

```
$ whois techsteroid.com | grep "Name Server"
   Name Server: NS-1129.AWSDNS-13.ORG
   Name Server: NS-159.AWSDNS-19.COM
   Name Server: NS-1846.AWSDNS-38.CO.UK
   Name Server: NS-635.AWSDNS-15.NET
```

Furthermore, the DNS records themselves look good:

```
$ dig +short www.techsteroid.com
techsteroid.com.
52.8.152.90
```

Here's the site screenshot:
[image: website screenshot]

So, any issue you're seeing locally are likely due to cache issues. Either your browser is caching old data, or something between your browser and the server is caching old data. Try a different browser, or connecting from a network different than the one you're currently using.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41076/discussion-on-answer-by-eeaa-hosted-on-aws-still-page-not-available).